# show payment receipt in woocommerce thankyou page with custom payment gateway?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-redirect

I'm developing a payment gateway for WooCommerce with my client's bank that provides an API and actually I can process the payment correctly, but I need to show the transaction receipt in the thankyou page, actually I know how to modify that template, but what I need at this moment is use the response from the bank API in the template for show the receipt that is generated by the bank and is sent in the response body, this is how I actually process the payment:

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
                global $woocommerce;
                $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

                $curl = curl_init();

                $data = array(
                    "KeyId" =>  $this->private_key,
                    "PublicKeyId"=> $this->public_key,
                    "Amount"    => $order->get_total(),
                    "Description"   => "Some Description Here",
                    "CardHolder"    => ($_POST['card-holder-same'] == 1 ) ? $_POST['billing_first_name']." ".$_POST['billing_last_name'] : $_POST['cp_wc_cch_fname']." ".$_POST['cp_wc_cch_lname']  ,
                    "CardHolderID"  => $_POST['cp_wc_cch_id'],
                    "CardNumber"    => $_POST['cp_wc_ccNo'],
                    "CVC"           =>  $_POST['cp_wc_cvv'],
                    "ExpirationDate"    => $_POST['cp_wc_expdate'],
                    "StatusId"  => $this->pay_type,
                    "IP"    => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                    "OrderNumber" => $order->get_order_number()

                );

                curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.url/payment",
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                      "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    ),
                ));

                $response = curl_exec($curl);
                $err = curl_error($curl);

                curl_close($curl);

                if ($err) {
                    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
                } else {
                    $resp = json_decode($response);
                    if($resp->success == 1){
                        $order->payment_complete();
                        $order->reduce_order_stock();
                        $order->add_order_note( 'Gracias su pago ha sido procesado Exitosamente!', true );
                        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

        // Redirect to the thank you page
                        return array(
                                'result' => 'success',
                                'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
                        );
                    }else {
                        print_r($order->get_user());
                        wc_add_notice(  'Intenta Nuevamente', 'error' );
                        return;
                    }
                }

    }
```

until there the code works just great, I need some help is in the redirect part,

```
// Redirect to the thank you page
                        return array(
                                'result' => 'success',
                                'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
                        );
```

I need send this response to that page so I can extract the voucher (transaction receipt) to show it to the customer.
this is a response I'm actually getting for the bank API.

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "Pago Aprobado",
"id": "57e25f73-85e2-40a4-aed1-3ad8012c2623",
"code": "201",
"reference": "794283",
"voucher": "\r\n&lt;table style=&quot;background-color: white;&quot;&gt;\r\n    &lt;tbody&gt;\r\n        &lt;tr&gt;\r\n            &lt;td&gt;\r\n                &lt;div style=&quot;border: 1px solid #222; padding: 9px; text-align: center; max-width:255px&quot; id=&quot;voucher&quot;&gt;\r\n\r\n                    &lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;\r\n                        .normal-left {\r\n                            font-family: Tahoma;\r\n                            font-size: 7pt;\r\n                            text-align: left;\r\n                        }\r\n\r\n                        .normal-right {\r\n                            font-family: Tahoma;\r\n                            font-size: 7pt;\r\n                            text-align: right;\r\n                        }\r\n\r\n                        .big-center {\r\n                            font-family: Tahoma;\r\n                            font-size: 9pt;\r\n                            text-align: center;\r\n                            font-weight: 900;\r\n                        }\r\n\r\n                        .big-center-especial {\r\n                            font-family: Tahoma;\r\n                            font-size: 9pt;\r\n                            text-align: center;\r\n                            font-weight: 900;\r\n                            letter-spacing: .9em;\r\n                        }\r\n\r\n                        .big-left {\r\n                            font-family: Tahoma;\r\n                            font-size: 9pt;\r\n                            text-align: left;\r\n                            font-weight: 900;\r\n                        }\r\n\r\n                        .big-right {\r\n                            font-family: Tahoma;\r\n                            font-size: 9pt;\r\n                            text-align: right;\r\n                            font-weight: 900;\r\n                        }\r\n\r\n                        .normal-center {\r\n                            font-family: Tahoma;\r\n                            font-size: 7pt;\r\n                            text-align: center;\r\n                        }\r\n\r\n                        #voucher td {\r\n                            padding: 0;\r\n                            margin: 0;\r\n                        }\r\n                    &lt;/style&gt;\r\n                    &lt;div id=&quot;voucher&quot;&gt;\r\n                        &lt;table&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;normal-center&quot;&gt;COPIA - CLIENTE&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;big-center-especial&quot;&gt;\r\n                                    &lt;br /&gt;\r\n                                    BANESCO\r\n                                &lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;big-center&quot;&gt;\r\n                                    &lt;br /&gt;\r\n                                    \r\n                                &lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; style=&quot;height: 8px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;TECNOLOGIA INSTAPAGO&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;DEMOSTRACI&amp;#211;N&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;J-000000000&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; style=&quot;height: 8px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;2&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;000000000000&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;2&quot; class=&quot;normal-right&quot;&gt;000000000000&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;1&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;FECHA:&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;3&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;00/00/00 00:00:00 PM&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;1&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;NRO CUENTA:&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;2&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;000000******0000    &lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td class=&quot;normal-right&quot;&gt;&#39;0&#39;&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;NRO. REF.:&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;000000&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td class=&quot;normal-right&quot;&gt;LOTE:&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td class=&quot;normal-right&quot;&gt;000&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;1&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;APROBACION: &lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;3&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;000000&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;1&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;SECUENCIA:&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;3&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; style=&quot;height: 8px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;big-center&quot;&gt;\r\n                                    &lt;br /&gt;\r\n                                    MONTO BS.  0,00\r\n                                &lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; style=&quot;height: 8px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr style=&quot;margin-top: 10px;&quot;&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;big-center&quot;&gt;RIF: J-000000000&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; style=&quot;height: 8px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;\r\n                                    &lt;b&gt;\r\n                                        &lt;br /&gt;\r\n                                    &lt;/b&gt;\r\n                                &lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;4&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;\r\n                                    &lt;br /&gt;debito\r\n                                &lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                            &lt;tr&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;1&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;ID:&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;3&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;000000000000000000&lt;/td&gt;\r\n                            &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n                        &lt;/table&gt;\r\n                    &lt;/div&gt;\r\n                &lt;/div&gt;\r\n            &lt;/td&gt;\r\n        &lt;/tr&gt;\r\n    &lt;/tbody&gt;\r\n&lt;/table&gt;\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
"ordernumber": "45289652",
"sequence": "794283",
"approval": "794283",
"lote": "794283",
"responsecode": "00",
"deferred": false,
"datetime": "11/8/2018 11:43:52 AM",
"amount": "1,258.43",
"authid": null,
"idmerchant": null,
"terminal": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and use the WC session:

Documentation URL:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session.html

StackOverflow discussion.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199656/how-to-use-session-in-woocommerce-pages-like-we-use-normal-php-session

And once you get to the Thank you page you'll destroy it.

Haven't tried it yet by coding it but that should work.